# How to query NOT LIKE any string in an array on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I need to get all the records where a specific key has a value NOT LIKE any strings in a specific array on MongoDB using the aggregation framework. MRE below.

```
[
    {
        "data":"ABCD"
    },
    {
        "data":"ABCDE"
    },
    {
        "data":"ABBD"
    },
    {
        "data":"ABBBD"
    }
]
```

Query all records where "data" value NOT LIKE any string in ["ABC", "ABBB"]

Expected Result:

```
[
    {
        "data":"ABBD"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) and [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in this way:

```
db.collection.find({
  "data": {
    "$nin": [
      {
        "$regex": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "$regex": "ABBB"
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LjESK7P05rf)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forgot to mention, but the array has 1k+ elements, so this option isn't feasible.

Comment: Further, I'm getting a "cannot nest $ under $in" error message.